# Visual studio code php color not showing in html file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use PHP code in visual studio code HTML file but couldn't get the color highlight. I have installed PHP Intellisense but still the same

```htm
<div class="htmlcolor">
  <?php
  echo "php color not working in html file";
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: hi davis i could only insert a code which actually doesn't really help to see the colour in visual studio code . I couldn't insert image, i'm new here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rename your file from `your-file.html` to `your-file.php` to enable PHP code highlighting for both `html` and `php`

Comment: so is it the only method around to change extension and change back later? i've tried to find setting as well as extension, haven't got any clue

Comment: you can also change the language on the visual studio in the bottom right of the window

Comment: @jx1986 why would you change from PHP back to HTML if it's going to be running PHP in the file?

Comment: @crescentfresh the file source code contains mix programming languages

Comment: @jx1986 like javascript? or? Just seeing because if it's JS you can keep it php

Answer (score 2):

Usually this has to do with a VS code plugin that is conflicting with another formatting plugin.  I've disabled all Formatting plugins and re-enabled only `Prettier` and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In VS-Code, install the extension `PHP Extension Pack`. This will help you with highlight colors, auto-complete, suggestions etc. :) And yes, as mentioned by dstrants, you should keep your code in a php file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .html file, and then look at the bottom-right corner of the Visual Studio Code window. You'll find the language mode displayed in the status bar. It will have HTML by default, but change it to PHP.